# Fitting Dataset Histogram (3 categories)

Tags: tikz-pgf, histogram

I am struggling with a Tikz figure. As you can se in the picture, there are three different Histograms, each for a specific Survey. The problem is that i can't fit the first and the second histogram into the figure, possibly by reducing the gap between each histogram, as well as the their respective x labels. Changing the axis width does not help. It would be also nice to add 2 vertical lines, to separate the three histograms. Do anyone of you know how to solve this problem? Thank you in advance

[image]

```
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
calculate offset/.code={
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
\pgfmathsetmacro\testmacro{(\pgfplotspointmeta       *10^\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@EXPONENT@y)*\pgfplots@y@veclength)}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
},
every node near coord/.style={
/pgfplots/calculate offset,
yshift=-\testmacro
},
}
\pgfplotstableread{
0 62 6 6 6 9 2 2 2 0 3 
1 53 13 10 5 6 3 2 2 1 4
2 58 15 11 5 5 1 1 1 1 1      
}\dataset
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar,
width=16cm,
height=8cm,
ymajorgrids,
ymin=0,
ymax=70,        
ylabel={\%},
xtick=data,
xticklabels = {
\textbf{1989-1993},
\textbf{1994-1998},
\textbf{2005-2009},
},
xticklabel style={yshift=-3ex},
major x tick style = {opacity=0},
minor x tick num = 1,
minor tick length=1ex,
every node near coord/.append style={
anchor=north,
}
]
\addplot[draw=black,fill=black!30, nodes near coords=1] table[x index=0,y   index=1] \dataset; %Data1
\addplot[draw=black,fill=black!30, nodes near coords=2] table[x index=0,y index=2] \dataset; %Data2
\addplot[draw=black,fill=black!30, nodes near coords=3] table[x index=0,y index=3] \dataset; %Data3
\addplot[draw=black,fill=black!30, nodes near coords=4] table[x index=0,y index=4] \dataset; %Data4
\addplot[draw=black,fill=black!30, nodes near coords=5] table[x index=0,y index=5] \dataset; %Data5
\addplot[draw=black,fill=black!30, nodes near coords=6] table[x index=0,y index=6] \dataset; %Data6
\addplot[draw=black,fill=black!30, nodes near coords=7] table[x index=0,y index=7] \dataset; %Data7
\addplot[draw=black,fill=black!30, nodes near coords=8] table[x index=0,y index=8] \dataset; %Data8
\addplot[draw=black,fill=black!30, nodes near coords=9] table[x index=0,y index=9] \dataset; %Data9
\addplot[draw=black,fill=black!30, nodes near coords=10] table[x index=0,y  index=10] \dataset; %Data10
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete minimal code that is compilable without manual changes. And is the `\testmacro` code really necessary in order to explain the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify `enlarge x limits`. In axis units, the distance between the centers of the categories is 1, so a suitable distance from the first/last x-coordinate to the edge of the axis is 0.5. Remember that the bars in a category is centered on the x-coordinate. And to do that, you can add

```
enlarge x limits={abs=0.5}
```

to the axis options.

For the vertical lines, seeing as you have already added minor ticks between the categories, you just need to activate the grid, with `xminorgrids`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
calculate offset/.code={
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
\pgfmathsetmacro\testmacro{(\pgfplotspointmeta       *10^\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@EXPONENT@y)*\pgfplots@y@veclength)}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
},
every node near coord/.style={
/pgfplots/calculate offset,
yshift=-\testmacro
},
}
\pgfplotstableread{
0 62 6 6 6 9 2 2 2 0 3 
1 53 13 10 5 6 3 2 2 1 4
2 58 15 11 5 5 1 1 1 1 1      
}\dataset
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar,
width=16cm,
height=8cm,
ymajorgrids,
xminorgrids, %% added
ymin=0,
ymax=70,        
ylabel={\%},
xtick=data,
xticklabels = {
\textbf{1989-1993},
\textbf{1994-1998},
\textbf{2005-2009},
},
xticklabel style={yshift=-3ex},
major x tick style = {opacity=0},
minor x tick num = 1,
minor tick length=1ex,
every node near coord/.append style={
anchor=north
},
enlarge x limits={abs=0.5}  %% added
]
\addplot[draw=black,fill=black!30, nodes near coords=1] table[x index=0,y   index=1] \dataset; %Data1
\addplot[draw=black,fill=black!30, nodes near coords=2] table[x index=0,y index=2] \dataset; %Data2
\addplot[draw=black,fill=black!30, nodes near coords=3] table[x index=0,y index=3] \dataset; %Data3
\addplot[draw=black,fill=black!30, nodes near coords=4] table[x index=0,y index=4] \dataset; %Data4
\addplot[draw=black,fill=black!30, nodes near coords=5] table[x index=0,y index=5] \dataset; %Data5
\addplot[draw=black,fill=black!30, nodes near coords=6] table[x index=0,y index=6] \dataset; %Data6
\addplot[draw=black,fill=black!30, nodes near coords=7] table[x index=0,y index=7] \dataset; %Data7
\addplot[draw=black,fill=black!30, nodes near coords=8] table[x index=0,y index=8] \dataset; %Data8
\addplot[draw=black,fill=black!30, nodes near coords=9] table[x index=0,y index=9] \dataset; %Data9
\addplot[draw=black,fill=black!30, nodes near coords=10] table[x index=0,y  index=10] \dataset; %Data10
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```